# Query optimization for index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a System and a Report model. System has_many reports and Report belongs_to system. Each daily report consists of 175 records per system.

I need a query on my system#index page which should list all systems filtered on most recent report creation. This was my first attempt.

```
@systems = System.joins('LEFT JOIN reports ON reports.system_id = systems.id').group('systems.id').order('MAX(reports.created_at) ASC')
```

This lists systems with a report (System Load (2.1ms)) but sorted by system_id not by report created_at.

Second attempt

```
@systems = System.joins(:reports).where("reports.created_at = (SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM reports p group by system_id having p.system_id = reports.system_id)").order('reports.created_at DESC')
```

This query does the job, but is really slow ( System Load (546.2ms)), despite having an index on report.created_at.

Third attempt

```
@systems = System.joins(:reports).where("reports.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM reports p group by system_id having p.system_id = reports.system_id)").order('reports.id DESC')
```

Also does the job, slightly faster than the second attempt (System Load (468.3ms)) but still not fast enough.

Any tips?

**EDIT 03032017**

I did the numbers on a small test dataset

old query

```
SELECT s.* FROM systems s
JOIN reports r ON r.system_id = s.id
WHERE r.created_at = (
  SELECT MAX(created_at)
  FROM reports p
  group by p.system_id
  having p.system_id = r.system_id)
ORDER BY r.id DESC

Time: 622.683 ms
```

Philip Couling solution (clean, returns only systems with reports)

```
SELECT systems.*
FROM systems
JOIN (
  SELECT reports.system_id
    , MAX(reports.created_at) created
  FROM reports
  GROUP BY reports.system_id
) AS r_date ON systems.id = r_date.system_id
ORDER BY r_date.created;

Time: 1.434 ms
```

BookofGreg solution (will give me all systems, report or no report)

```
select systems.* from systems order by updated_at;

Time: 0.253 ms
```

I couldn't get systemjack's solution to work.

Fastest solution: bookofgreg

Cleanest solution: philip couling

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An index on `(reports.system_id, reports.created_at)` **might** make this work efficiently:

```
@systems = System.joins(:reports).where("reports.created_at = (SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM reports p where p.system_id = reports.system_id) system_id)").order('reports.created_at DESC')
```

---

Alternativly...

Your second piece of code:

```
System.joins(:reports).where("reports.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM reports p group by system_id having p.system_id = reports.system_id)").order('reports.id DESC')
```

expands to:

```
   SELECT system.*
     JOIN reports ON system.id = reports.system_id
    WHERE reports.created_at = (
                           SELECT MAX(created_at) 
                             FROM reports p 
                         group by p.system_id 
                           having p.system_id = reports.system_id)
                       )
 ORDER BY reports.id DESC
```

Notice how it has to look at reports twice.  Also, because you include `p.system_id = reports.system_id)` the nested query will be called once per system record.

Ideally you want to get a list of system_ids and report dates:
So...

```
    SELECT reports.system_id
         , MAX(reports.created_at) created
      FROM reports
  GROUP BY reports.system_id
```

And then join to that:

```
  SELECT systems.* 
    FROM systems
    JOIN (
           SELECT reports.system_id
                , MAX(reports.created_at) created
             FROM reports
         GROUP BY reports.system_id
         ) AS r_date ON systems.id = r_date.systems_id
ORDER BY r_date.created
```

Comment: Really happy with this reply, thanks for the explanation. Will try this out tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution, if you do not need the report data on the page, is have Report `after_save -> { self.system.touch } # in Report` when it is updated. This will cause the System's `updated_at` to take on the time the Report was updated.

This will mean you can just sort the System by their updated at without joining at all.

This solution assumes that there is no other way to update System. If there is then you can specify a time cache column which you can use to order on like `after_save -> { self.system.touch(:report_cached_updated_at) }`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-touch

Comment: Thanks a lot, this looks promising. I am referencing the report data in my view but only the last report date, which in this solution will be the same as the system_updated at.

Comment: No problem :) Solved this for myself just last week on a has_many :through relation that wanted to show the most-recently-updated thing's status.
Remember to accept if it works for you, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html) might perform well for you. Not sure how to implement this in rails, but the query to get the latest report for each system could look like:

```
select * from (
    select s.*, r.sytem_id, r.created_at,
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY s.id ORDER BY r.created_at desc) AS row
    from systems s
    left join reports r on r.system_id = s.id
) where (row = 1 OR r.system_id is null)
```

The check for null is there because you have a left join in your example so you must want systems even if there is no report.

or simpler (but not as sure syntax is right):

```
select *
from systems s
left join reports r on r.system_id = s.id
having (r.system_id is null
    OR row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY s.id ORDER BY r.created_at desc) = 1)
```

Comment: Appreciate your input. From a technical point of view I think Philip Couling and your answer are the purest. If I look at performance gain, I'm leaning towards BookofGreg. The daily automatic reports import come from a 3rd party API and consists of aproximatley 87000 records, new systems are automatically added to the (static) system table. So I think avoiding a join altogether might suit my needs best :-)